# Would it be more correct to call a polar bear a "preyer" , a "predator", or a "hunter"?

Tags: word-choice

My little son is due to make a small brochure about the polar bear according to his kindergarten teacher's arrangement.

He intends to name the brochure "Polar Bear: the Hunters on Ice".

I, however, think it somewhat inaccurate to call a polar bear a "hunter". The predatory ways of the *ursus* species are different from those of top feline animals such as tigers and lions which are more usually called "hunters".

I am unsure as to what the most correct way to refer to polar bears might be. "Preyers on ice"? "Arctic predators"? Is there something more appropriate to call them?

Comment: How do you define *hunter*?  I just recently watched a movie on the Arctic, where a polar bear hunted down a female and two cubs over the course of several days and  many miles of ice and water.

Comment: I think, for animals, "a hunter" means an animal that chase and kill its prey. Maybe "hunter" is also a proper title. But is "predator" more sicentific than "hunter"? Is "a predator on ice" a correct expression?

Comment: *Preyer* is no longer used.  There are no examples of *preyer* in [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/).  (It still appears as the name Preyer.)

Comment: Yes, *Predators on ice* is a valid expression, and so is hunter.  [predator](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/predator) means *any animal or other organism that **hunts** and kills other organisms (their prey), primarily for food*  But if you son chose *hunter* why not let him choose his own title?

Comment: Yeah, why not? And, is "Polar Bear: the Hunters on Ice" as a title of the brochure grammatically correct?

Comment: I'd make *Bears* plural:  Polar Bears: The Hunters on Ice.

Comment: I agree that *predators on ice* is a valid expression, but if I heard it out of context, I'd think it was an [ice show](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_theatre) called *Predators on Ice*, because so many ice shows have titles that fit the template "\_\_\_\_ on ice".  (Don't let that stop you from using it, though!)

Comment: For his context, *hunter* and *predator* are effectively synonyms, but noting that your son is "little", it would probably be more natural for him to use the most common word. Google Books claims 78M instances of *hunter*, and only 2.3M instances of *predator*, so I think the choice is obvious.

Comment: @Fumble - I would expect _hunter_ to be more predominant because it's used in more contexts. The Polar Bear is a hunter. So was [Elmer Fudd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elmer_Fudd). There are clothing and equipment lines for hunters, but not predators. Moreover, Hunter is one of the more common last names in the U.S. (#154 on [this list](http://names.mongabay.com/data/1000.html)), which could account for several hits. In this case, the more common word happens to be a good choice for the young lad, but I don't think that would necessarily be "obvious," since it depends on a range of factors.

Comment: @J.R.: Below a certain age OP's son wouldn't be likely to even *know* the word "predator". Given he has a kindergarten teacher, I suspect such words would simply be advertising the fact that he's probably *not* using **his own words** in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - No disagreement from me with that part of your reasoning. I just wanted to issue a caveat to the 78M vs 2.3M remark.

Comment: There's no reason to have the definite article in a title, especially if it's pluralized. *Polar Bears: Hunters on Ice* is vastly better than *Polar Bears: the Hunters on Ice*.

Comment: @martha But on the ice the polar bear is the [apex predator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apex_predator), so perhaps the use is excusable. I'd certainly buy it with a singular *hunter*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this context, I can't think of any reason why I'd prefer *hunter* over *predator*, or vice-versa. Stay away from *preyer*, though. That's a rarely-seen word that sounds rather awkward, I think.

If the words were being applied to people instead of animals, however, there is a huge difference in meaning. If I heard someone say, "My neighbor is a hunter," I would assume that the neighbor hunts animals during hunting season (in the U.S., that would most likely be deer, but it could also be ducks, pheasants, or other wildlife). However, if someone said, "My neighbor is a predator," I would assume that person engages in some kind of unscrupulous behavior. One dictionary defines predator as: [*One that victimizes, plunders, or destroys, especially for one's own gain*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/predator).

Rest assured, though, in the context of polar bears on ice (or leopards on the savannah), there is no reason to fear such a misinterpretation. When describing animals, I think *predator* and *hunter* are largely synonymous and interchangeable.